# Does "User name may not be same as computer name" apply to active directory user names

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, netbios

I was going through this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310845

> If you try to create a user account on a computer and try to use the
>   computer name for the user account name, you receive the following
>   error message:
>
> ***The user name may not be the same as the computer name computer name***
>
> This behavior occurs to prevent users from creating user names with
>   the same user name as the computer's name. This check is made to
>   prevent problems with programs that use NetBIOS name registrations,
>   which can mistakenly use the 03 NetBIOS entry (registered in this case
>   by the user), rather than the 20 NetBIOS entry, which represents the
>   workstation's Server service. Such errors can prevent programs from
>   working properly.

In our network computers are named after their users and the same usernames are used in active directory. e.g. John's computer name is `JOHN` and his Active Directory login name is `FABRICAM\John`. Does the article apply in this scenario? Should we expect "undesired behavior" during network activity because of this?

Comment: You've answered your own question. The users pre-Windows 2000 logon name is Fabricam\John but his user logon name is John, so obviously that isn't restricted while also having a computer named John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create users with the same names as computers in Active Directory.  The user account will be john@domain.com, and the computer's name will be john$@domain.com or domain\john$.  This check only applies to creating a *local* user named john on a computer named john.